# How do I make a text to binary?

Tags: python, binary

So I have been trying to make a text to binary converter but what I do is I convert every single letter and symbol to the binary equivalent but as you can imagine this takes long and i'm wondering if there is a shorter way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text to binary convert :

```
name = "Name"
binary = ' '.join(format(ord(x), 'b') for x in name)
```

Binary to Text :

```
binary = '100001'

binary_values = binary.split()

ascii_string = ""
for binary_value in binary_values:
    an_integer = int(binary_value, 2)

    ascii_character = chr(an_integer)

    ascii_string += ascii_character

print(ascii_string)
```

Here is my [git repo](https://github.com/Istiakshovon/binary/blob/master/main.py)

Answer (score 0):

This programm convert text to binaries list :

```python
a_string = "abc"

a_byte_array = bytearray(a_string, "utf8") #Create bytearray

byte_list = []

for byte in a_byte_array:
    binary_representation = bin(byte) #Convert to binary

    byte_list.append(binary_representation) #Add to list


print(byte_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of binary modules on [PyPI](https://pypi.org). You could just have the input go through one and print the result.